# Java Scanner Class bad character "®"

Tags: java, unicode

I have a scanner class reading a file into a string. Any file with this character "®" causes it to fail. I'm new to Java, Is there a better way to read this file so that character would be accepted?

```
public void readFile(String fileName)
{
    fileText = "";

    try
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while (file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            fileText += line +"\r"+"\n";
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println(e);

   }
      }
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: If possible could you use hexdump -C to put small section of the file containing the (R) character...

Comment: “Any file with this character "®" causes it to fail.” How can you tell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default Scanner uses the platform default character encoding, this might not match the character encoding of the file. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-) states:

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the
>   specified file. Bytes from the file are converted into characters
>   using the underlying platform's default charset.

First determine what character encoding your file is in, this can be done with the Linux command line utility `file -i`. Pass the correct encoding into the scanner. Java 7 contains predefined constants in [java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) for some well known character sets.

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: "determine what character encoding your file" reading around it looks like that is a common issue? Anyone have a better way then best guess?

Comment: @Minerbob One is supposed to know in advance which encoding their data files are using. If you're in the business of opening any random files customers might send you, then yes, an intelligent guess is the best option.

Answer (score 10):

Mention the encoding when you create the scanner.

`Scanner file= new Scanner(new File(fileName), "utf-8");`

Comment: I was using BlueJ it wouldn't throw a error it was just exit the loop and leave my string empty.

Comment: Thank you for the lead, utf-8 didn't work for me but when I used ISO-8859-1  it did. Looks like I need to read up a little bit. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to mention the encoding UTF-8 while creating instance of the Scanner Class, Thats it.